# Monospaced font choice with Material Design

Tags: web-app, typography, material-design, monospaced-font

In our application, we adhere to Material Design as much as possible. But the Material Design specification doesn't include any information about a monospaced font. I need to render a set of tables with numbers that change periodically, and stay perfectly lined up. That seems like a job for a monospaced font, but neither Roboto or Noto have monospace options.

What's a good approach to monospace within Material Design? Is there a better approach to keeping columns of numbers straight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's Roboto Font has a Monospaced Variation known as **Roboto Mono**:

Download it here: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto+Mono

This will be perfectly valid while following Material Design guidelines.

Comment: Glad to see you stick to the guidelines, Dan!